# How to show Tooltip on click of mat-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular 15.1.3` with `Angular Material 14.0.4`

Below is the code that shows the Tooltip on hover of the Mouse pointer to `mat-icon`

```
<p class="text-primary inactive-label">
    <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" [matTooltip]="userTitle" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipShowDelay="500">no_users</mat-icon> 
    <span class="deactivation-title">User Deactivated on 1st April 2023</span>
</p>
```

How can I change it to display same Tooltip on click of mat-icon instead of hovering of Mouse Pointer?

Comment: Hello guys! Please help me out... Is it possible to make this change?

Comment: Any suggestions at least?

Comment: I am ok if I am using totally different component instead of this mat-icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to show the tooltip manually
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#manually-calling-show-and-hide

Link the tooltip with empty tag, and add click event to icon
Example:

```
<mat-icon (click)="tooltip.toggle()" [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}">no_users</mat-icon>
<span
  #tooltip="matTooltip"
  matTooltipTouchGestures="off"
  matTooltip="userTitle"
  matTooltipPosition="above"
  matTooltipShowDelay="0"
></span>
<span>User Deactivated on 1st April 2023</span>
```

Comment: I tried your code. It is working on click of the `mat-icon`. But it still displays tool tip on hover of this text - `User Deactivated on 1st April 2023`. How to stop that?

Comment: You should add 2 span. The first has nothing as @helper told. And the second span has "User Deactivated on 1st April 2023" text